# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A signing key must be specified if the specified JWT is digitally signed

Tags: java, jjwt

I'm looking to implement `JWT` in my application for that I'm doing some R&D on it by taking a reference from : https://stormpath.com/blog/jwt-java-create-verify. I was successfully able to implement the `generateToken()` method, when I am trying to `verifyToken()` by extracting claim sets. I dont understand from where `apiKey.getSecret()` is came from. Could you please guide me on this?

The code below for reference:

```
public class JJWTDemo {

    private static final String secret = "MySecrete";

    private static String generateToken(){
        String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-", "");
        Date now = new Date();
        Date exp = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000*30)); // 30 seconds

        String token = Jwts.builder()
                .setId(id)
                .setIssuedAt(now)
                .setNotBefore(now)
                .setExpiration(exp)
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, secret)
                .compact();

        return token;
    }

    private static void verifyToken(String token){
        Claims claims = Jwts.parser().
                setSigningKey(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(apiKey.getSecret()))
                .parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
        System.out.println("ID: " + claims.getId());
        System.out.println("Subject: " + claims.getSubject());
        System.out.println("Issuer: " + claims.getIssuer());
        System.out.println("Expiration: " + claims.getExpiration());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(generateToken());
        String token = generateToken();
        verifyToken(token);
    }
}
```

I see the below error is coming:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJqdGkiOiI4N2E5NmYwNTcyN2M0ZDY0YjZmODlhNDAyOTQ2OTZiNyIsImlhdCI6MTQ4NDQ4NjYyNiwibmJmIjoxNDg0NDg2NjI2LCJleHAiOjE0ODQ0ODY2NTZ9.ycS7nLWnPpe28DM7CcQYBswOmMUhBd3wQwfZ9C-yQYs
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A signing key must be specified if the specified JWT is digitally signed.
    at io.jsonwebtoken.lang.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:85)
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:331)
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:481)
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parseClaimsJws(DefaultJwtParser.java:541)
    at io.jsonwebtoken.jjwtfun.service.JJWTDemo.verifyToken(JJWTDemo.java:31)
    at io.jsonwebtoken.jjwtfun.service.JJWTDemo.main(JJWTDemo.java:41)
```

Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>${jjwt.version}</version>
        </dependency>
<jjwt.version>0.7.0</jjwt.version>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`apiKey.getSecret()` in the blog article is a reference to the secure, randomly-generated & Base64-encoded secret key (like a password) assigned to the API Key that Stormpath provides every customer.  Stormpath customers use this API key to authenticate every request into the Stormpath REST API.  Because every Stormpath customer has an API Key (and the key is accessible to your application), the API Key secret is an ideal 'default' for signing and verifying JWTs specific to your application.

If you don't have a Stormpath API Key, any sufficiently strong secure-random byte array will be just fine for signing and verifying JWTs.

In your above example, the following is shown as a test key:

```
private static final String secret = "MySecrete";
```

This is not a valid (JWT-compliant) key, and it cannot be used for JWT HMAC algorithms.

The JWT RFC *requires* that you [MUST](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7518#section-3.2) use a byte array key length equal to or greater than the hash output length.

This means that if you use HS256, HS384, or HS512, your key byte arrays must be 256 bits (32 bytes), 384 bits (48 bytes), or 512 bits (64 bytes) respectively.  I go into more detail on this in [another StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40274325/407170) - see the data there, and the `MacProvider` examples that can generate you a spec-compliant and secure key.

Based on this, here is that code sample, rewritten to a) generate a valid key and b) reference that key as a Base64-encoded string:

```
import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;
import io.jsonwebtoken.impl.crypto.MacProvider;

import java.security.Key;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.UUID;

public class JJWTDemo {

    private static final Key secret = MacProvider.generateKey(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256);
    private static final byte[] secretBytes = secret.getEncoded();
    private static final String base64SecretBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(secretBytes);

    private static String generateToken() {
        String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-", "");
        Date now = new Date();
        Date exp = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000 * 30)); // 30 seconds

        String token = Jwts.builder()
            .setId(id)
            .setIssuedAt(now)
            .setNotBefore(now)
            .setExpiration(exp)
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, base64SecretBytes)
            .compact();
        
        return token;
    }

    private static void verifyToken(String token) {
        Claims claims = Jwts.parser()
            .setSigningKey(base64SecretBytes)
            .parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
        System.out.println("ID: " + claims.getId());
        System.out.println("Subject: " + claims.getSubject());
        System.out.println("Issuer: " + claims.getIssuer());
        System.out.println("Expiration: " + claims.getExpiration());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(generateToken());
        String token = generateToken();
        verifyToken(token);
    }
}
```

Note that Base64-encoded byte arrays are *not* encrypted (text encoding != encryption), so ensure that if you Base64-encode your secret key bytes that you still keep that Base64 string safe/hidden.

Finally, the above static final constants (named `secret`, `secretBytes` and `base64SecretBytes`) are there for this simple test demonstration only - one should never hard code keys into source code, let alone make them static constants, as they can easily be decompiled.

Comment: How can I work for `ECDSA using SHA-512` algorithms?

Answer (score 0):

I am 100% agree on Les Hazlewood. But we should always send the `Subject`, `Issuer` and `Audience` to identify the current login users more details. The code can be modified like below:

```
import java.security.Key;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.UUID;

import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;
import io.jsonwebtoken.impl.crypto.MacProvider;

public class TokenUtil {
    private static final Key secret = MacProvider.generateKey(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256);
    private static final byte[] secretBytes = secret.getEncoded();
    private static final String base64SecretBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(secretBytes);

    private static String generateToken(String subject, String issuer, String audience) {
        String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-", "");
        Date now = new Date();
        Date exp = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000 * 30)); // 30 seconds

        String token = Jwts.builder()
                .setId(id)
                .setIssuedAt(now)
                .setNotBefore(now)
                .setExpiration(exp)
                .setSubject(subject)
                .setIssuer(issuer)
                .setAudience(audience)
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, base64SecretBytes)
                .compact();

        return token;
    }

    private static void verifyToken(String token) {
        Claims claims = Jwts.parser()
                .setSigningKey(base64SecretBytes)
                .parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();

        System.out.println("----------------------------");
        System.out.println("ID: " + claims.getId());
        System.out.println("Subject: " + claims.getSubject());
        System.out.println("Issuer: " + claims.getIssuer());
        System.out.println("Expiration : " + claims.getExpiration());
        System.out.println("Not Before : "+claims.getNotBefore());
        System.out.println("Audience :: "+claims.getAudience());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String token = generateToken("MySubject", "AH", "MyAudience");
        System.out.println("TOKEN :: "+token);
        verifyToken(token);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To generate token :

```
    AppUser appUserPrincipal = (AppUser) authentication.getPrincipal();

    return Jwts.builder()
            .setSubject((appUserPrincipal.getUsername()))
            .setIssuedAt(new Date())
            .signWith(getKey(), SignatureAlgorithm.HS512)
            .compact();
    }


    public Key getKey() {
      byte[] keyByte = Decoders.BASE64.decode(jwtSecret);
      return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(keyByte);
    }
```

And then get the userName (subject) from token using this code :

```
    public String getUserNameFromJwtToken(String token) {
          return Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(getKey()).build()
            .parseClaimsJws(token).getBody().getSubject();
    }
```